# how to import library? android studio 1.4

Tags: android, import, module

I want to know how to import this library in my project using Android Studio 1.4

https://github.com/Ghedeon/SlideToUnlockProject

I know it's a silly question, and is not the first time asked here. But i dont understand how is the procedure.

Thank You.

Comment: You said it has already been asked before, but still you don't understand the procedure. It would help if you indicated the answers you have found, and the parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download .zip
Unzip :)
Android Studio->File->New->Import Module...
Source directory: Select the root of the library folder you unzipped...
Wait for Gradle to sync.
In your `<root project folder>/<app folder/build.gradle` (the one that contains `apply plugin:   'com.android.application'`) add to your dependencies
`dependencies {
compile project(':SlideToUnlock')
...
}`
And done :)